# how to catch the click event on a leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet

I'm having multiple popups on a leaflet map open at the same time, and they can overlap. I want to bring a popup to front if clicked on. While I have no trouble getting the click on the map with `map.on('click', function(e) {do something;});` I can't seem to do the same thing with a popup.

How can i catch the click event on a L.Popup?

Comment: As an alternative, consider only opening a single popup at a time. Leaflet has direct support for this, and it is [what they recommend in their docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup). Of course, since your use-case might not allow for this, it is just a recommendation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The setContent method of L.Popup accepts HTML elements so you could do something like this:

```
var content = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'content'),
    popup = L.popup().setContent(content);

L.DomEvent.addListener(content, 'click', function(event){
    // do stuff
}, context);
```

Reference:

https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil

https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event

Comment: Or you can bind event to `L.popup#_contentNode` or `L.popup#_container`(although they are considered private) directly: `L.DomEvent.on(popup._contentNode, 'click', function(e) { /* blah */ });`

Comment: @Mics I ended up doing this as a quick and dirty solution. I attached the event to popup._wrapper, as that one is always visible.