# move a leaflet.js popup to front

Tags: leaflet

I have a map with multiple popups open at the same time. A popup contains a tweet, and the user needs to quickly scan the content, hence why multiple popups are open at the same time.

When I click on a popup I want it to move in front of all the others. While I can catch the right popup, there is no `bringToFront()` on a popup like on other layers, and the `zIndexOffset` is also not defined.

Has anybody succeeded in getting a popup to move to the front? Is manipulating the css zindex the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the popup bound to a marker or poly, i would use the bringToFront() function of the marker or poly. If that won't work for you, i would suggest extending L.Popup and take a good look at L.Marker to see how they implemented the bringToFront and setZIndex functionality. In there you could also add the click event functionality from your previous problem: [how to catch the click event on a leaflet popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848786/how-to-catch-the-click-event-on-a-leaflet-popup)

L.Marker source @ https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/marker/Marker.js

Comment: The popups are added directly to the map. I'll have a look at the marker code.