# click event on leaflet popup content

Tags: jquery, html, css, leaflet, popup

I am trying to access content in a leaflet popup. Specifically I have added a form with buttons inside it which I would like to access. But for now I just try to add an event to the popup itself.

```
$(".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper .leaflet-popup-content").click(function(e) {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

[LeafletJs](https://leafletjs.com/) Example of marker with popup:

```
<form class="popup-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="mb-0" for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" class="comment">${feature.properties.note}</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Save</button>
    <button class="delete-button btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ml-auto">Delete</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Code where popup content is set

```
var points = new L.geoJson(null, {

  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.note);

    let myPopup = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'content');

    content = `
    <form class="popup-form">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="mb-0" for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" class="comment">${feature.properties.id}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Save</button>
        <button class="delete-button btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ml-auto">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    `;

    layer.bindPopup(content); // Create empty popup

    $('#form', myPopup).on('click', function() {
      alert("form clicked")
  });
```

Insipred by this post [how to catch the click event on a leaflet popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848786/how-to-catch-the-click-event-on-a-leaflet-popup)

I dont understand what the 'context' of this code example is?

```
var content = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'content'),
    popup = L.popup().setContent(content);

L.DomEvent.addListener(content, 'click', function(event){
    // do stuff
}, context);
```

Comment: Which element exactly do you want to access? Is the form code placed inside the popup?

Comment: I added the code I am working with. 
My goal is to get the click event on the delete button (to delete..) and also the save button to do an update request to db. 
I am trying adding a listener manually at the moment as of my update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to get access to the delete button class one way would be to use `on("popupopen") event` on `layer.bindPopup(popupContent)`

Using this way there is no need of using leaflet's `L.DomUtil`. 
While listening to the `popupopen event` you can listen to jquery's `click event` using delete button's class to call the delete event from the delete button respectively. Use `preventDefault` to avoid page refresh.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  const popupContent = `
    <form class="popup-form">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="mb-0" for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" class="comment">${
          feature.properties.id
        }</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex">  
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Save</button>
        <button class="delete-button btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ml-auto">
           Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    `;

  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
  }

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent).on("popupopen", () => {
    $(".delete-button").on("click", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(`now delete layer with id ${feature.properties.id}`);
    });
  });
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l228r5qry)

Comment: This is great, thank you! That worked just like I needed :)